# Bullets wants not work when it over a image

Tags: php, css

The onclick wont works when it in the photo.

It works when it not in the image, see here
https://i.gyazo.com/805a6984f4221745bdaf34c6f60c8216.gif

```html
/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}



/* Caption text */
.text {
  margin-top: -50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
/* Caption text */
.text2 {
  padding: 230px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  left: 50px;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;

}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}




</style>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">

  <img draggable="false" src="http://habboo-a.akamaihd.net/c_images/web_promo/lpromo_army15_generic1.png" style="width:759" height="300">
 <div class="text"> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
  </div>
 
 <div class="text2"><a href="{url}/news/{newsID-1}">{newsTitle-1}</a></div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img draggable="false" src="http://habboo-a.akamaihd.net/c_images/web_promo/lpromo_army15_generic1.png" style="width:759" height="300">
   <div class="text"> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
  </div>
  <div class="text2"><a href="{url}/news/{newsID-1}">{newsTitle-2}</a></div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img draggable="false" src="http://habboo-a.akamaihd.net/c_images/web_promo/lpromo_army15_generic1.png" style="width:759" height="300">
   <div class="text"> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
  </div>
  <div class="text2"><a href="{url}/news/{newsID-1}">{newsTitle-3}</a></div>
  
</div>



</div>
<br>
 

</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>
```

And when the bullets are in the image. Nothing hapend with the onclick. Here is a image to show:
https://i.gyazo.com/4dd2adb59e1e6ca5a1ebbae4ce9c5aa1.gif

Comment: raise your bullet's container `z-index` in your css.

Comment: what did you do? show your code and tell me what doesnt work.